# content being pushed down in ie6

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-6

Here is a sample of the type of page that is getting messed up in ie6 on our website:

[sample page](http://cms.burlington.ca/page7360.aspx)

In ie6, the main content area is being pushed down below the left column navigation.

Much of my workplace is still using ie6 so we need to solve this issue. We've tried doing different ie6 hacks but have had no success.

Any ideas??

Comment: Got to love government and their no upgrade policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having IE6 it's a bit difficult to test however my guess would be that your container, `.container_16` is just not wide enough for IE6.

This would account for the content being pushed below the left hand navigation bar.

You can test this by putting the following into the head of your HTML page:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <style type="text/css">
      .container_16{width: 1500px !important;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It worked! I didn't go as high as 1500px...only had to go to 980px. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Change the width on the content id to 720px:

```
#content
{
    width: 720px;
}
```

You have it at 740px ... but I changed it to 720px in Firefox and it looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing margins on .grid_4 and maybe also the negative ones on #content, your two main columns.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your typical box-model problem. Do you have the width and padding and/or margin defined in the same class? Here's a good overview of the issue: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200612/internet_explorer_and_the_css_box_model/